# jQuery first() not working as expected - returning container instead

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple layout like this..

```js
 
  $('#link5').on('click', function(event) {
  
      console.log("Link Clicked");
      
      var $element = $( this );
      
      container = $element.closest('.container');
      

      
      first = container.first();
      
      console.log(first);
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

    <div class="item1">
        <div class="itemcontainer">
            Item 1
            <a id="link1" class="customlink" href="#">
                Click
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item2">
        <div class="itemcontainer">
            Item 2
            <a id="link2" class="customlink" href="#">
                Click
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item3">
        <div class="itemcontainer">
            Item 3
            <a id="link3" class="customlink" href="#">
                Click
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item4">
        <div class="itemcontainer">
            Item 4
            <a id="link4" class="customlink" href="#">
                Click
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item5">
        <div class="itemcontainer">
            Item 5
            <a id="link5" class="customlink" href="#">
                Click
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item6">
        <div class="itemcontainer">
            Item 6
            <a id="link6" class="customlink" href="#">
                Click
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>
    
    <div class="item7">
        <div class="itemcontainer">
            Item 7
            <a id="link7" class="customlink" href="#">
                Click
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I am trying to get the first item `item1` when link 5 is clicked, but it is showing me the container.

am I using `first` wrong?

Comment: `first()` means “first in this set”, not “first child.” So the first in the set of one is the container itself. You’ll need to select the first of `children()` probably

Comment: Well you're not using it wrong but you're expecting it to do something different than what it actually does. If you have a jQuery object referring to a list of DOM elements, then `.first()` reduces it to just the first object. It does not do any further traversal or searching in the DOM.

Comment: If it were me I'd make sure all those "item" `<div>` elements had  the specific class *plus* a generic class like "item".

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you're calling `first()` on the `.container` itself. If you want to get the `.item1`, then call `first()` on the `children()` of the container:

```
let first = container.children().first();
```

```js
$('#link5').on('click', function(event) {
  var $element = $(this);
  let container = $element.closest('.container');
  let first = container.children().first();  
  console.log(first);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">
    <div class="itemcontainer">
      Item 1
      <a id="link1" class="customlink" href="#">
        Click
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <div class="itemcontainer">
      Item 2
      <a id="link2" class="customlink" href="#">
        Click
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    <div class="itemcontainer">
      Item 3
      <a id="link3" class="customlink" href="#">
        Click
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item4">
    <div class="itemcontainer">
      Item 4
      <a id="link4" class="customlink" href="#">
        Click
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item5">
    <div class="itemcontainer">
      Item 5
      <a id="link5" class="customlink" href="#">
        Click
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item6">
    <div class="itemcontainer">
      Item 6
      <a id="link6" class="customlink" href="#">
        Click
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item7">
    <div class="itemcontainer">
      Item 7
      <a id="link7" class="customlink" href="#">
        Click
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code as below:

```
 $('#link5').on('click', function(event) {

      console.log("Link Clicked");

      var $element = $( this );

      container = $element.closest('.container');
      first = container.find("div:first-child");

      console.log(first);

  });
```

Your current code is not working as `first()` will return first element having container class which is not required in your case. Hope it helps you.